# How to remove trailing slashes in gatsby project?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

i'm facing trailing slash issue in my gatsby project. when i'm trying to reload or trigger an url **Ex:website.com/page1**, just for second it is loading url with trailing slash like **website.com/page1/** and then it is going back to **website.com/page1**. its happening to every page . I have tried remove trailing slashes plugin but didn't get the result

I will be grateful for any help.
Thank you.

Comment: How are you building the pages? Dynamically or in the /pages folder? Can you share your `gatsby-node.js`?

Answer (score 5):

Since `gatsby@4.7.0` was release they added **trailingslash** option

you can do:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    // ...
  ],
  trailingSlash: "always",
};
```

- `always`: Always add trailing slashes to each URL, e.g. /x to /x/.
- `never`: Remove all trailing slashes on each URL, e.g. /x/ to /x.
- `ignore`: Don't automatically modify the URL

you can find more information on https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-config/#trailingslash

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I avoid this issue:

1. Make sure that all links link to the trailing slash version of the page, e.g. `<Link to="/some/path/">…</Link>`
2. When generating pages in `gatsby-node.js` via the `createPage` API call, always specify the `path` with a trailing slash
3. Configure the server to serve pages like `about.html` from requests to `/about/` (Netlify calls this “Pretty URLs”)
4. Ensure the server is configured to respond with directory indexes and looks for an `index.html` file to serve as the directory index; disable automatic indexes for good measure
5. Ensure the server responds with the directory index for both versions of the path (with and without trailing slash)

In most circumstances you'll only need to worry about #1 and #2, but if that doesn't fix it for you keep going down the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Nginx settings to redirect each tailing slash URL to non-trailing slash URL i.e your website.com/page1/ redirect to website.com/page1 URL

for this nginx pattern of rewrite rule like   **rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;**

```
 server {

    listen       81 default_server;
    listen       [::]:81 default_server;
    server_name  example.ubuntu.com;


    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

    root         /home/bhupesh/Public/Work-Space/auth-ui/public;


    index index.html;


     try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }


}
```

**another Solution** is install plugin

```
npm install --save-dev gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes
```

Then configure via **gatsby-config.js**

```
  {
      ...
      plugins: [
        ...,
        `gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes`,
      ]
    }
```

This plugin is intended to remove trailing slashes from paths generated by Gatsby itself.

This however does not prevent the resolution of pages that have trailing slashes, due to the way browsers are built to interpret URLs as paths.

This means that a user will need to take the extra step of ensuring that all router links direct towards paths that do not end in a slash.

For example,  will render the view related to /about but will display as /about/ in the browsers address bar.

This is an important factor when relying on path driven logic, such as in the use case of the Link components activeClassName and activeStyle props.

For example, if the current route is /about, the component <Link to="/about/" activeStyle={{ color: 'rebeccapurple' }}> wouldn't match because of the slash.

Comment: The `gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes` will be deprecated soon in favor of [trailingSlash config option](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-config/#trailingslash)